# Centering css grid container

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to make my image gallery app as responsive as possible. As I am using auto-fill with minmax in the grid template columns (see code below), the number of columns reduce when the page width gets to a certain size and adds rows instead.

The problem I am having is that when the number of columns reduce, a large empty void is left on the right hand side. When the number of columns reduce I want the all the images (so the images container) to be centered but I can't seem to get this to work?

Here is an image of what the page looks like when it is full screen:

[image]

Here is what it looks like when the page gets reduced in width. This is when I want the images to be centered so that there is equal void space on either side (the page width in pixels here is 568):

[image]

Here is the relevant html:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="image-container" *ngFor="let image of galleryList" [ngClass]="generatingClassName(image)">
    <div *ngIf="checkLike(image.imagePath) && isLoggedIn" class="heart-icon-container">
      <ion-icon name="heart" class="heart-icon" (click)="updateLike(image.imagePath)"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!checkLike(image.imagePath) && isLoggedIn" class="heart-icon-container">
      <ion-icon name="heart-outline" class="heart-icon" (click)="updateLike(image.imagePath)"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <img [src]="image.imagePath" alt="Praying to the Sun" class="image" (click)="onImageSelected(image)">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.gallery-container {
    margin-top: 110px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(106px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
    justify-items: center;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    gap: 4px;
    height: 800px;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;

}


.image-container {
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-template-columns: 1; 
    grid-template-rows: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px white solid;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. I'm not sure but if you use `inline-grid` it will remove the space, then center as you would with any inline container : `text-align:center` on the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would I be able to use this alongside the CSS grid setup that I have though?